# regex 13 digits phone number with dash

Tags: regex

I have an application that needs to handle validation for phone numbers. Phone numbers are required to have 13 characters (sum of numbers and dashes). There must be at least 1 dash and a maximum of 3 dashes. The starting character must be a digit. How can I create a regex for this validation? Here is my regex string. `/^(?:[0-9]-*){13}$/` It doesn't work exactly what I expected

Comment: Can hyphens appear at the start and end of the string, are two consecutive hyphens allowed?

Comment: hyphens can not appear at the start and end of the string and two consecutive hyphens are not allowed. Sorry, I didn't describe it well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So 13 characters in total with a maximum of 3 dashes and a minimum of 1 means 10 digits right? Therefor your characters are ranging 11-13?

If so, try:

```
^(?=(?:\d-?){10}$)\d+(?:-\d+){1,3}
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/X08fWZ/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?=` - Open a positive lookahead:

  - `(?:` - Open a non-capture group:

    - `\d-?` - Match a digit and optional hyphen.
    - `){10}$)` - Close the non-capture group and match it ten times before the end-string anchor. Then close the lookahead.
- `\d+` - 1+ Digits.
- `(?:` - Open a 2nd non-capture group:

  - `-\d+` - Match an hyphen and 1+ digits.
  - `){1,3}` - Close non-capture group and match it 1-3 times.

Comment: 13 characters in total with a maximum of 3 dashes and a minimum of 1 means the digit must contain a maximum of 12  and a minimum of 10. That regex above doesn't work very well

Comment: But the man above gave me an excellent answer. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: Right, that was my quesiton in the first line. The other answer does what you are after well enough then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
^(?=.{13}$)[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+){1,3}$
^(?=.{13}$)\d+(?:-\d+){1,3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jzsSi6/2/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{13}$)` - the string must contain exactly 13 chars
- `[0-9]+` / `\d+`  - one or more digits
- `(?:-[0-9]+){1,3}` / `(?:-\d+){1,3}` - one, two or three repetitions of a hyphen followed with one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D.%7B13%7D%24)%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A-%5Cd%2B)%7B1%2C3%7D%24):

[image]

A JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['123-4567-8901','123-45-67-890','123-456728901','1234567890123','123--67890123','-234567890123','123456789012-','-23456789012-'];
const regex = /^(?=.{13}$)\d+(?:-\d+){1,3}$/;
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text, "=>", regex.test(text));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed the number of digits are not known.  I am looking for number of dashes between 1 and 3 between the numbers

```
texts = ['1-2-3-4-5','123-4567-8901','123-45-67-890','123-456728901','1234567890123','123--67890123','-234567890123','123456789012-','-23456789012-']

for text in texts:
    print(text,re.findall(r"^\d+-?\d+-?\d+-?\d+$",text))
```

output:

```
1-2-3-4       ['1-2-3-4']
123-4567-8901 ['123-4567-8901']
123-45-67-890 ['123-45-67-890']
123-456728901 ['123-456728901']
1234567890123 ['1234567890123']
123--67890123 []
-234567890123 []
123456789012- []
-23456789012- []
```